# Dying Actors in Rubinius or are threads/processes sandboxed?

Tags: multithreading, actor, rubinius

I am looking into Rubinius (2.0+) and its actors library for parallel computing challenges.

I am wondering what would happen if an actor for example eats up loads and loads
of memory up to the point where it throws a OutOfMemoryException.
Does only this one actor dies or does this kill the whole rubinius process?

To put in more generic words:
Are Actors/Threads in Rubinius sufficiently isolated from each other that
a dying thread will not kill the whole system?

Best regards

Robert

Comment: oh heck! I didnt even realize it until you wrote your comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I checked the sources the actors in rubinius where simply mapped onto threads (one per actor) so running out of memory would kill your whole process.

All the rules applying to threads should apply to the currently actors implementation.